# Counting items within a value found inside mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below I have a basic SQL query on a table called `foodBasket`. This table on has three fields. The most important fields are `type` and `details` . Is there a way I can count items with in a field? For example, `type` = `Veggies` has `details` = `Broccoli, Carrots, Lettuce, Celery`. I would like to return a numerical value for details of `4` , which represents all items. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0267b/2)

```
CREATE TABLE foodBasket
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     type varchar(100), 
     details varchar(100)
    );

INSERT INTO foodBasket
(type, details)
VALUES
('Veggies', 'Broccoli, Carrots, Lettuce, Celery'),
('Fruits', 'Bannana, Apple, Orange, Guava')
```

Comment: It appears to be equal to the number of commas + 1 (which is the same a length of string - length of string without commas. A better idea would be normalization

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I would like to return a numerical value for details of 4 , which represents all items"

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean by normalization? could you please show me?

Comment: No. That's what google is for.

Comment: @Strawberry are you sure you can't explain database normalization in the comments section of a Stack Overflow question? ;)

Comment: @Zane haha! most likely the case.. jk. Maybe you can help, What can you tell me about normalization in relations to this example?

Comment: Normalization is THE. SINGLE. MOST. IMPORTANT. CONCEPT. in relation to relational databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Normalize your database,only if you are not able to modify the database you can do it like this:

```
    select id, type, details,
    case details when null then 0 
    when '' then 0
    else
    (LENGTH(details) - LENGTH(replace(details, ',', '')) +1) 
    end
as details_count
    from foodBasket
```

Counting the commas if the details its not null, will give you the amount of items in the fields if details its not empty or null.

Here is in the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0267b/11/0)

Comment: Great! is there away i can assign this to a variable like `details_count`?

Comment: This returns all the foodBasket table, so you cant store it like that, but you can name that column with as details_count. What are you doing with this query?

Comment: I *hope* we're accepting this solution because of the first sentence as opposed to what comes after ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry some times you just cant change the database. Anyway in this case now that i read the comments it just seem like the users just does not know about normalization.

Comment: Luis, you can *always* change the database. But you can't change people

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `array()` that way all its items can be counted using http://php.net/array_count_values